# CMake: Library not found -ljsoncpp

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm very new in C++ and CMake.

In my project I use `jsoncpp` library and my IDE(CLion) see it without any problems. However when I try to compile it I get this error message:

`ld: library not found for -ljsoncpp`

Here is my project structure:

```
/
|-jsoncpp/  /*Here contains source code, not compiled library*/
|
|-work_7/
|  |-main.cpp
|
|-CMakeList.txt
```

Here is `CMakeList.txt` config:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.4)
project(programming_practice)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
set(SOURCE_FILES work_7/main.cpp)

add_executable(programming_practice ${SOURCE_FILES})
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/jsoncpp/include)
add_subdirectory(jsoncpp)

target_link_libraries(programming_practice jsoncpp)
```

So what I did wrong? Please help me.

Comment: What does "My IDE **see** library" means? If it sees why it doesn't compile? BTW, `ld` is a linker. Do you have jsoncpp compiled?

Comment: @drop it means when I type #include " IDE suggest me this library.

Comment: If you're new in C++, you could try [biicode](https://www.biicode.com/) because [jsoncpp library block is uploaded in biicode](https://www.biicode.com/hithwen/jsoncpp) and it's so easy to use in your projects. If you're interested of reuse this code, read the getting started webpage, http://docs.biicode.com/c++/gettingstarted.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you need to compile jsoncpp first to a library before using it.
Use `add_subdirectory(jsoncpp)` and make sure you have Cmake file in that directory for compilation.

Comment: Why **dynamic** library?

Answer (score 5):

You also need to specify where the library for `jsoncpp` is located. Add this to your `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
link_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/jsoncpp/lib)
```

That path should be the one containing the file named: `libjsoncpp.o` or the equivalent in your S.O.